Updating a Reactive Object in a Shiny Dashboard
I'm wanting to make a dashboard to track fitness activities.
I'm using googlesheets as the backend storage.
When the app opens it draws down all the activities from Today / Yest. / DayBeforeYest.
The first screen of the app shows all the toggles for the activities available for Today
The toggles are pre_loaded with their "current statuses" as per the googlesheet datasource.
There is another toggle that swaps between Today / Yest. / DayBeforeYest.
Currently when I swap between days, any changes I've made (say to the activity toggles for Today) are no longer there when I toggle back to that day.
It feels like I need some reactive object that
is initially just the original statuses (as downloaded from googlesheets)
but I want it to be updated with the changes I make to the toggles (for each activity on each day) each time the switches are pressed.
The goal is for me to upload changes to googlesheets only after I hit an "upload" button (but I've got that covered already).

library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)




timeframes <- 
  tribble(
    ~date_name, ~date,
    "Today", today()
    , "Yesterday", today()-1 
    , "Day before yesterday", today()-2
  )




pre_assignment_vector <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~feature, ~date_name, ~value,
    "bike_into_coworking_space", "Day before yesterday",  FALSE,
    "bike_into_coworking_space", "Today",  FALSE,
    "bike_into_coworking_space", "Yesterday",   TRUE,
    
    "yoga", "Day before yesterday",  FALSE,
    "yoga", "Today",  FALSE,
    "yoga", "Yesterday",   TRUE
  ) %>% 
  mutate(value_name = paste0(feature, "_", snakecase::to_snake_case(date_name), "_status"),
         input_id_destination = paste0(feature, "_switch")
  )



assignment_vector <- 
  pre_assignment_vector %>% 
  filter(date_name == "Today")


map2(assignment_vector$value_name, assignment_vector$value, ~assign(.x, .y, envir = .GlobalEnv))


###################################################################

reactive_store_of_values_obj <- reactive(pre_assignment_vector)


###################################################################

# a function for when the date toggle is pressed

update_switches_to_date_selected <- function(reactive_store_of_values_obj, timeframe_selected) {
  
  
  # timeframe_selected <- "Yesterday"
  # reactive_store_of_values_obj <- pre_assignment_vector
  
  
  values_to_update_to <- 
    reactive_store_of_values_obj %>% 
    filter(date_name == timeframe_selected)
  
  status_vals <- values_to_update_to
  
  map2(status_vals$input_id_destination, status_vals$value, ~updateSwitchInput(inputId = .x, value = as.logical(.y)))
  
  
}


###################################################################

# a function to update the persistent "stor of values" object whenever any toggles are pressed.
# using hte date toggle input varable to determine the day

update_the_reactive_store_of_values_obj <- function(reactive_store_of_values_obj
                                                    , timeframe_selected = input$timeframe_selected
                                                    , yoga_switch = input$yoga_switch
                                                    , bike_into_coworking_space_switch = input$bike_into_coworking_space_switch) {
  
  
  # reactive_store_of_values_obj <- pre_assignment_vector
  # timeframe_selected <- "Yesterday"
  # yoga_switch <- yoga_today_status
  # bike_into_coworking_space_switch <- bike_into_coworking_space_today_status
  
  
  new_values_from_inputs <- 
    tibble(yoga_switch = yoga_switch,
           bike_into_coworking_space_switch = bike_into_coworking_space_switch) %>% 
    gather(input_id_destination, new_value) %>% 
    mutate(date_name = timeframe_selected)
  
  
  
  reactive_store_of_values_obj %>% 
    left_join(new_values_from_inputs, by = join_by(date_name, input_id_destination)) %>% 
    mutate(value = coalesce(new_value, value)) %>% 
    select(-new_value)
  
  
}



###################################################################




ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    
    fluidRow(
      
      h3("Timeframe"),
      
      sliderTextInput(inputId = "timeframe_selected",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = rev(timeframes$date_name),
                      selected = timeframes$date_name[1])
    ), 
    
    
    fluidRow(
      
      column(width = 2, h4("Yoga")), 
      column(width = 1, prettySwitch(inputId = "yoga_switch", label = NULL, value = as.logical(yoga_today_status))),
      
      
    ), 
    
    
    fluidRow(
      
      column(width = 2, h4("Bike into Coworking Space")), 
      column(width = 1, prettySwitch(inputId = "bike_into_coworking_space_switch", label = NULL, value = as.logical(bike_into_coworking_space_today_status)))
      
    ) 
    
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, input$timeframe_selected, {
    
    # update inputs to the newly selected date's values
    update_switches_to_date_selected(reactive_store_of_values_obj = reactive_store_of_values_obj(), timeframe_selected = input$timeframe_selected)
    
  })
  
  
  
  
  ###################################################################
  all_inputs_watch_list <- reactive(
    list(
      input$yoga_switch
      , input$bike_into_coworking_space_switch
    ))
  
  
  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, all_inputs_watch_list(), {
    
    print("switch used")
    
    reactive_store_of_values_obj <- reactive(update_the_reactive_store_of_values_obj(reactive_store_of_values_obj()))
    
    
    
    
  })
  
  
  
}





shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)





It would be hard to help you unless you post some sample data and some of the changes you are making on the server side.

Thanks @YBS, I've managed to get some help on a solution... I'll post it here shortly

I got some help for a solution (I don't quite fully understand it yet but it works.
Within the server, I needed to initiate the persistent reactive object like so...
  reactive_object <- reactiveValues(store_of_values = NULL)
  
  observe({reactive_object$store_of_values <- pre_assignment_vector})


Then all references to "reactive_store_of_values_obj()" could then be replaced with "reactive_object$store_of_values"
EG
update_switches_to_date_selected(reactive_store_of_values_obj = reactive_object$store_of_values, timeframe_selected = input$timeframe_selected)

reactive_object$store_of_values <- update_the_reactive_store_of_values_obj(reactive_object$store_of_values, input$timeframe_selected, input)


Here is the full code again, with those corrections made
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)



timeframes <- 
  tribble(
    ~date_name, ~date,
    "Today", today()
    , "Yesterday", today()-1 
    , "Day before yesterday", today()-2
  )




pre_assignment_vector <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~feature, ~date_name, ~value,
    "bike_into_coworking_space", "Day before yesterday",  FALSE,
    "bike_into_coworking_space", "Today",  FALSE,
    "bike_into_coworking_space", "Yesterday",   TRUE,
    
    "yoga", "Day before yesterday",  FALSE,
    "yoga", "Today",  FALSE,
    "yoga", "Yesterday",   TRUE
  ) %>% 
  mutate(value_name = paste0(feature, "_", snakecase::to_snake_case(date_name), "_status"),
         input_id_destination = paste0(feature, "_switch")
  )



assignment_vector <- 
  pre_assignment_vector %>% 
  filter(date_name == "Today")


map2(assignment_vector$value_name, assignment_vector$value, ~assign(.x, .y, envir = .GlobalEnv))



###################################################################

# a function for when the date toggle is pressed

update_switches_to_date_selected <- function(reactive_store_of_values_obj, timeframe_selected) {
  
  
  # timeframe_selected <- "Yesterday"
  # reactive_store_of_values_obj <- pre_assignment_vector
  
  
  values_to_update_to <- 
    reactive_store_of_values_obj %>% 
    filter(date_name == timeframe_selected)
  
  status_vals <- values_to_update_to
  
  map2(status_vals$input_id_destination, status_vals$value, ~updateSwitchInput(inputId = .x, value = as.logical(.y)))
  
  
}


###################################################################

# a function to update the persistent "stor of values" object whenever any toggles are pressed.
# using hte date toggle input varable to determine the day

update_the_reactive_store_of_values_obj <- function(reactive_store_of_values_obj
                                                    , timeframe_selected
                                                    , input) {
  
  
  
  # timeframe_selected <- "Yesterday"
  # reactive_store_of_values_obj <- pre_assignment_vector
  # 
  # input <- list(
  #   yoga_switch = yoga_today_status,
  #   bike_into_coworking_space_switch = bike_into_coworking_space_today_status
  # )
  
  
  
  new_values_from_inputs <- 
    tibble(yoga_switch = input$yoga_switch,
           bike_into_coworking_space_switch = input$bike_into_coworking_space_switch) %>% 
    gather(input_id_destination, new_value) %>% 
    mutate(date_name = timeframe_selected)
  
  
  
  reactive_store_of_values_obj %>% 
    left_join(new_values_from_inputs, by = join_by(date_name, input_id_destination)) %>% 
    mutate(value = coalesce(new_value, value)) %>% 
    select(-new_value)
  
  
}



###################################################################




ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    
    fluidRow(
      
      h3("Timeframe"),
      
      sliderTextInput(inputId = "timeframe_selected",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = rev(timeframes$date_name),
                      selected = timeframes$date_name[1])
    ), 
    
    
    fluidRow(
      
      column(width = 2, h4("Yoga")), 
      column(width = 1, prettySwitch(inputId = "yoga_switch", label = NULL, value = as.logical(yoga_today_status))),
      
      
    ), 
    
    
    fluidRow(
      
      column(width = 2, h4("Bike into Coworking Space")), 
      column(width = 1, prettySwitch(inputId = "bike_into_coworking_space_switch", label = NULL, value = as.logical(bike_into_coworking_space_today_status)))
      
    ) 
    
    
    
    
  )
)






server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  reactive_object <- reactiveValues(store_of_values = NULL)
  
  observe({reactive_object$store_of_values <- pre_assignment_vector})
  
  
  
  
  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, input$timeframe_selected, {
    
    # update inputs to the newly selected date's values
    update_switches_to_date_selected(reactive_store_of_values_obj = reactive_object$store_of_values, timeframe_selected = input$timeframe_selected)
    
  })
  
  
  
  
  ###################################################################
  all_inputs_watch_list <- reactive(
    list(
      input$yoga_switch
      , input$bike_into_coworking_space_switch
    ))
  
  
  
  
  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, all_inputs_watch_list(), {
    
    print("switch used")
    
    
    reactive_object$store_of_values <- update_the_reactive_store_of_values_obj(reactive_object$store_of_values, input$timeframe_selected, input)
    
    
  })
  
  
  
}





shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

